# Question about using rvest and purrr for scraping multiple pages with nested links

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

I have written the code below to extract all speeches given by the FLOTUS at this [link](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/remarks-and-statements-the-first-lady-laura-bush). Here is the code:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url_base <- "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/remarks-and-statements-the-first-lady-laura-bush?page=%d"

map_df(1:17, function(i) {

  # simple but effective progress indicator
  cat(".")

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))

  data.frame(name=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".views-field-title-1.nowrap")),
             title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "td.views-field-title")),
             year=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".date-display-single")),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}) -> flotus
```

I would like to use this code to extract the *text* of the corresponding speeches as well. Does anyone know how to do that with the code I've already written? If so, what would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs to retrieve the 'href' attribute links from the table's Title column using the `html_attr()` function.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url_base <- "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/remarks-and-statements-the-first-lady-laura-bush?page="

flotus <-map_df(1:16, function(i) {
   
   # simple but effective progress indicator
   cat(".")
   
   pg <- read_html(paste0(url_base, i))
   
   #parse the table
   df <- html_node(pg, "table") %>% html_table()
   
   #obtain the href from the table's Title column
   df$links <-html_nodes(pg, "td.views-field-title") %>% 
                         html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href")
   df
})
```

The above code will add the link to the speech as an additional column in the data frame.

**Part Two**
To extract the text of the speeches, retrieve the list of links and then loop through the list, open the page, extract the desired information, store it and repeat.

```
#limited the number of pages request for debugging
map_df(flotus$links[1:3], function(link){
   print(link)
   #Read page
   page <- read_html(link)
   #extract the content and other info
   content <- page %>% html_node("div.field-docs-content") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
   person <- page %>% html_node("div.field-docs-person") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
   citation <- page %>% html_node("div.field-prez-document-citation") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
   
   #add it to a data struture
   data.frame(content, person, citation)
   
   Sys.sleep(1) #Be polite - add a pause to prevent the appearance of attacking the server
})
```

Here all of the data is stored in a dataframe.  This data frame can then be joined with the dataframe from up above depending on future intentions.

Comment: Is this something that should be done outside of the function I've written? Also, I get this error when running the code you've written: `Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"`

Comment: The error is caused by trying to parse the 17th page.  For some reason, rvest is not detecting the table on that page.  Your code doesn't work either on page 17.  It is not obvious on the cause right now.  If you limit to 1 to 16, that is 800 out of 802 speeches, a good start for now :(

Comment: I have all the speeches I'm interested in (those of Melania Trump) from the code I initially posted. Could you tell me how to simply add to that code the text of the individual speeches?

Comment: Ok, here is the code that extracts the links: `data.frame(name=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".views-field-title-1.nowrap")),
             title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "td.views-field-title")),
             year=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".date-display-single")),
             html_nodes(pg, "td.views-field-title") %>% 
                         html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href"),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. What should I do to extract the text, though?